# ModuleNotFound Error with Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I installed numpy using conda (in an environment). I activated that environment and then created a python file,

```
import numpy as np
print("Hello")
```

This runs without any problems.

But, when I open a Jupyter Notebook (when the environment is still active) and the do the same `import numpy as np` command, I see a ModuleNotFound Error.

So I ran `pip install numpy` in Jupyter Notebook and it then installed the package. Now I am able to use numpy, but then, what is the point of me creating an environment and adding packages to it? Shouldn't I install everything in jupyter itself?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I always follow the instructions here: [creating-python-virtual-environment-and-how-to-add-it-to-jupyter-notebook-4cdb41717582](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/creating-python-virtual-environment-and-how-to-add-it-to-jupyter-notebook-4cdb41717582) - particularly the part about Adding virtual environment to JuPyter notebook - `python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=<name>`

Comment: What topsail said is the way to go. As to what is the point of creating the environment and adding packages to it...it is for project management and reproducibility down the road. If you do that and keep using the environment, you'll have what you need in one directory & things won't break on you six months from now when you return or when you move the environment to a new computer. Also, another tip if you are using conda, stick with it as best you can. Mixing in pip installation can lead you to need to troubleshoot some down the road when you try to be portable.

Comment: You could organize based on the notebook if you are not working local and working in temporary cloud instances/containers. However, you have to make sure someone (future you or other users) doesn't separate the install code from the other code. (You could inadvertently delete a cell easily.) And if you are doing that on a local machine, you are going to potentially needlessly install things in many places and take time to repeat installations. On the other hand if you aren't planning to be a major coder, then maybe the notebook as an organizing principle does make sense and is an option.